# Using dynamic JOIN with GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I would like convert the data in the source format into the target format.

SOURCE FORMAT:

```
OBJECT  PROPERTY  VALUE
M1      P1        V1
M1      P2        NULL
M2      P1        V2
M2      P1        V6
M2      P2        V3
M2      P2        V4
M2      P2        V5
```

TARGET FORMAT:

```
OBJECT  P1  P2  
M1      V1  NULL
M2      V6  V3
M2      V6  V4
M2      V6  V5    
M2      V2  V3                
M2      V2  V4
M2      V2  V5
```

I was not successful with using the PIVOT statement. It has to be dynamic-PIVOT since the values are unknown until run-time. Any help is appreciated. I use SQL Server 2014. Thank you

Comment: yes, pivot can be dynamic. You just prepare a string variable with your SQL query and then execute is as dynamic sql

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server doesn't have a DYNAMIC pivot command.

Comment: This doesn't really seem to be a PIVOT so much as a dynamic cross join... Let's say there was another value for object M2, property P1, would that produce 6 rows for M2 in the target format? (e.g. source includes values M2, P1, V6 => Target would include V2-V3, V2-V4, V2-V5, V6-V3, V6-V4, V6-V5?)

Comment: @BoltBait that doesn't mean you can't create a dynamic pivot....

Comment: Here is a great tutorial to get you started Thracian http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/

Comment: yes, @ZLK - i have updated the sample data set

Comment: Then what you want is dynamic joins, not so much a dynamic pivot...  I'll write a quick example of how it could be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So rather than pivoting, you're really just looking for dynamic joins (since each value is joining to each other value with a different property).

Here's an example of how you could do it.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX) = '', @joins NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @cols += ', T' + RN + '.[Value] ' + QUOTENAME([Property])
     , @joins += CHAR(10) + 'LEFT JOIN (SELECT [Value], [Object] FROM sourceTable WHERE [Property] = ''' + [Property] + ''') T' + RN + ' ON T1.[Object] = T' + RN + '.[Object]'
FROM (SELECT [Property], CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Property]) + 1 AS VARCHAR(50)) RN FROM sourceTable GROUP BY [Property]) T;

SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT T1.[Object]' + @cols +
'FROM (SELECT [Object] FROM sourceTable GROUP BY [Object]) T1' + @joins;

PRINT @SQL;
EXEC(@SQL);
```